# Jquery UI Sortable to "swap" list elements on collision

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, swap

How can I modify jquery ui sortable so I can drag an item from one list **on top of** an item in a second list and have the two items swap places upon drop?

https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists

Answer (score 0):

I used a combination of solutions to arrive at this, with #large_tiles and #small_tiles being two lists:

```
$(function() {
$("#large_tiles li, #small_tiles li").draggable({
    zIndex: 2,
    appendTo: "body",
});

initDroppable($("#large_tiles li, #small_tiles li"));

initSwap();
function initSwap() {
    initDroppable($("#large_tiles li, #small_tiles li"));
    initDraggable($("#large_tiles li, #small_tiles li"));
}
function initDraggable($elements) {
    $elements.draggable({
        zIndex: 2,
        appendTo: "body",
        helper: "clone",
        start: function(e, ui) {
            $(ui.helper).addClass("clone");
        },
        cursorAt: { left:50, top:75 }
    });
}
function initDroppable($elements) {
    $elements.droppable({
        activeClass: "active-tile",
        hoverClass: "hover-tile",
        over: function(event, ui) {
            var $this = $(this);
        },
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var $this = $(this);
            var linew1 = $(this).after(ui.draggable.clone());
            var linew2 = $(ui.draggable).after($(this).clone());
            $(ui.draggable).remove();
            $(this).remove();
            initSwap();
        }
    });
}
});
```